# How to avoid credit card number validation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

As I need to `stop credit card number validation in Magento 2` checkout page. How can I done this? Here is the error displayed in payment form,

[image]

**Note**

Am using `Paymetric extension` for credit card payment.

Comment: why you need to remove the card validation?

Comment: Am using tokenization, so I don't need card validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In paymentric module,vaidation should be happening in model folder,In model you have to find payment.php file and remove parent validation should be happening in validate function, as for your reference I attached code below

```
 public function validate()
    {
        /*
         * calling parent validate function
         */
//        parent::validate();  // command this parent validation
        return $this;
    }
```

**Note : Ime_Paymetrictokenize module used in my existing products**

Comment: I will check and let you know

Comment: This change working fine for my scenario, Thanks